# Servlet-database connection issue

Tags: mysql, database, servlets, jdbc

I am trying to connect a `servlet` with `mysql` database...but in the servlet code..
the statement:

`Class.forName(driver)` shows an error with red underline on tooltip-

```
 Syntax error on token-"driver",VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token.
```

I just can't get it why this happens..

here is the servlet code:

```
package Servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet  
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LoginServlet() 
    {
        super();
    }
   Connection con = null;

   String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";

   String db = "abc";

   String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

   Class.forName(driver);


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException

    {
        String username= request.getParameter("username");
        String password= request.getParameter("password");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("url+db","root","root");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        int val = st.executeUpdate("INSERT login values("+username+","+password+")");
        System.out.println("1 row affected");

        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put the

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

line just above

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("url+db","root","root");
```

Bear in mind that the servlet needs to be multi-threaded so that your

```
Connection con = null;
```

Will probably cause you problems when two users try to login at the same time.

Also, you need to close the connection properly

```
try {
    if(con != null)
      con.close();
      } catch(SQLException e) {}
```

and finally you will need to handle any exception that the database access may cause so wrap it in a try catch block.

```
package Servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet  
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public LoginServlet() 
{
    super();
}

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String db = "abc";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException

{
   try{
    Connection con = null;
    String username= request.getParameter("username");
    String password= request.getParameter("password");
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("url+db","root","root");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    int val = st.executeUpdate("INSERT login values("+username+","+password+")");
    System.out.println("1 row affected");

    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
  }catch(SQLException e){}
  finally{
    try {
      if(con != null)
       con.close();con=null;
       } catch(SQLException e) {}
  }

}
}
```

Or something like that.

As a final note it is much better to use a "connection pool".

Answer (score 0):

add a mysql connector 5.1.0 bin jar file.. add the jar file in your project library.

link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmysqldatabase1610jar.htm

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

```
Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rental","root","root" ) ;
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "select * from login";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score -1):

Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rental","root","root" ) ;

Comment: Your answer should contain an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.